# Mongo DB - Changing data type to Boolean resulting in object type

Tags: mongodb, types, mongo-shell

I am trying to update the data type of few fields from string to Boolean. I am using the following code in mongo shell :

```
db.SampleTest.find().forEach( function (d) {
d.smoke = new Boolean(d.smoke);
db.SampleTest.save(d);
});
```

But It updates the field as object type when viewed in mongodb compass. Please refer image

How to update the field type to Boolean?

Mongo Compass

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **MongoDB 4.2**, then below is the fix. You need to use [$toBool](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toBool/) and [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) operators.

```
db.SampleTest.find().forEach( function (d) {
    db.SampleTest.updateOne({"_id":d._id},[{"$set":{"smoke":{"$toBool": "$smoke"}}}])
})
```